# Pyspark : Model Loading multiple times with udf

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, data-science, user-defined-functions

Trying to apply udf on a large csv file that makes a model prediction based on some conditions, but for some reason the model is being loaded multiple number of times. Below is a sample snippet of how the flow looks like:

```
# main.py loads predict.py

from predict import predict_udf

data = spark.read("csv_path")
data.show()

| Column1  | Column2 |
| -------- | ------- |
|   Class1 |         |
|   Class2 |         |

data.withColumn("Column2",predict_udf(col("Column1"))
```

```
# predict.py

model = load_model() # Initialising model object

def predict(class_name):
    if class_name == "Class1":
        # Do something

    elif class_name == "Class2":
        # Do something else

predict_udf = udf(predict, StringType())
```

Ideally I was expecting the model to be loaded once since it is defined as a global variable, but the model is being loaded multiple number of times.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [broadcasting](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.Broadcast.html) the model to avoid unnecessary repetitive reads.

```
model = load_model() # Initialising model object
model_bc = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(model)
```

then you will be able to access initial `model` in udf via `model_bc.value` attribute.

This is a good [example](https://gist.github.com/smoothml/f8fc50274c9f9db7eb3ed57e2049ca7a) that illustrates complete solution.